# Does get() and onSnapshot() share the same cache internally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

(with offline mode enabled) when I invoke a `doc.get` somewhere in my app then later set up a listener `doc.onSnapshot` (for the same document) somewhere else, does the first call of `onSnapshot` listener reach for the same cached data that was grabbed by  `get` earlier (thus returning a result faster than having to hit the server for the first time) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is only one offline cache, and it's used no matter how you query for data while offline.